# Concrete5 website Security Warning on load

Tags: html, concrete5

I'm not really sure where to start here. Recently [our website](http://www.impactchoice.com), written using the Concrete5 CMS system, has started coming up with the following:

> Security Warning
>
> Do you want to run this application ?
>
> an unsigned application from the location below is requesting permission to run.
>
> Location: http://lifestylecommonplace.biz/.../
>
> running this application may be a security risk

How do I go about getting rid of this? I have no idea what to do here. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with an FTP access and injection was happening, cleaned all the php files by running a script to check all php files for the injected code and secured the FTP which had been setup via the WHM CP

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific, where does that happen? 
I went to your website and on the home page everything seems fine.

If the problem persists your server is probably infected thought and a quick search on google for http://lifestylecommonplace.biz/ brings up reports of viruses